# How to lay out specified number of objects per row?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have an angular project where I need to place items in a grid format. I need two items per row in a card-like format. For example, where my array is:

```js
myfruit:fruit[] = [new fruit(1,"apple","red fruit"),
                   new fruit(2,"banana","yellow fruit"),
                   new fruit(3,"orange","orange fruit")]
}

class fruit{
  public id:number;
  public name:string;
  public description:string;

  constructor(id:number,name:string,description:string){
    this.id=id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
  }
```

The corresponding HTML:

```html
<div *ngFor="fruit in myfruit">
  <div *ngFor="let i = 0; i < 2;i++">
    <h1>{{fruit.name}}</h1>
    <p>{{fruit.description}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Is this the correct way to lay out my items in rows of two?**

Comment: You would be better off just doing this with the CSS instead of trying to create some new wrapper element every X items

Comment: If you want to do it via javascript, you could chunk your collection by 2 and loop that on the outer layer. [Chunk function](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/278/how-to-split-an-array-into-chunks-of-the-same-size-easily-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it via javascript, you could chunk your collection by 2 and loop that on the outer layer.

```
<div *ngFor="let fruitChunk of chunkArray(myfruit, 2)">
  <div *ngFor="let fruit of fruitChunk">
    <h1>{{fruit.name}}</h1>
    <p>{{fruit.description}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Chunk function:

```
function chunkArray(myArray, chunk_size){
    var index = 0;
    var arrayLength = myArray.length;
    var tempArray = [];

    for (index = 0; index < arrayLength; index += chunk_size) {
        var myChunk = myArray.slice(index, index+chunk_size);
        // Do something if you want with the group
        tempArray.push(myChunk);
    }

    return tempArray;
}
```

Source: [Link](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/278/how-to-split-an-array-into-chunks-of-the-same-size-easily-in-javascript)

Comment: Please note that you must use `of` instead of `in` in the `ngFor` loop (it is a `for ... of` loop).